# no method named flush found for type std::io::Stdout in the current scope

Tags: rust

All the documentation I've found regarding flushing suggests that the proper way to flush stdout is as follows:

```
std::io::stdout().flush().expect("some error message");
```

This results in

> ```
> no method named flush found for type std::io::Stdout in the current scope
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to import the trait that implements the `flush` method for `Stdout`.

According to the documentation:

[image: io::Write]

Therefore:

```
use std::io::Write; // <--- bring the trait into scope

fn main() {
    std::io::stdout().flush().expect("some error message");
}
```

[Playground example](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=bf4ddbf23ef14d315d53c0a4b920c783&version=stable)

Comment: Why is this necessary?

Answer (score 19):

> Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Yes; **the compiler already does**.

```
fn main() {
    std::io::stdout().flush().expect("some error message");
}
```

```
error[E0599]: no method named `flush` found for type `std::io::Stdout` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:3:23
  |
3 |     std::io::stdout().flush().expect("some error message");
  |                       ^^^^^
  |
  = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
  = note: the following trait is implemented but not in scope, perhaps add a `use` for it:
          candidate #1: `use std::io::Write;`
```

Emphasis on the `help` and `note` lines - `use std::io::Write`.

All together:

```
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    std::io::stdout().flush().expect("some error message");
}
```